# Google drive php API authorization fails with invalid grant

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am using the **google drive API in PHP**. First I request an Auth url and send the user to that url. The user authorizes and is redirected to my url, with the authorization code in the query string, as intended. Next, I call `$client->authorize()` and pass in the code from the query string. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in
/home/a5874817/public_html/custom/google/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php:113
Stack trace:
#0 /home/a5874817/public_html/custom/google/src/Google_Client.php(131): Google_OAuth2->authenticate(Array, '4/jN5JfD_ejozBj...')
#1 /home/a5874817/public_html/custom/docs_reply.php(10): Google_Client->authenticate('4/jN5JfD_ejozBj...')
#2 {main}
thrown in /home/a5874817/public_html/custom/google/src/auth/Google_OAuth2.php on line 113
```

This account has authorized this app before, but the auth url has always included access_type=online, and it was more than an hour ago so the access token should have expired. What specifically might be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only online access, you will not be able to refresh a new access token when it runs out.

If you want permanent access, ask for access_type=offline, and make sure you store the refresh token for later use.

Comment: I am not refreshing, I am exchanging an auth code for an access token. I do not want access later, I mentioned the access type because I thought it might be relevant in some way I did not understand.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem has gone away, but I do not remember exactly which of the many changes I have made solved it. I think that the issue was that my auth url had the wrong kind of access_type in it or that the client was set up wrong. If anyone else has similar problems, I recommend making sure the scopes are correct and actually reading all of the auth url to make sure that it makes sense.